# XML sent via POST in PHP is not received

Tags: php, xml, post, http-headers

I am working with the [BlueHornet](http://www.bluehornet.com) API for sending email, specifically the **legacy.send_campaign** method.  I am updating a client's existing API calls and have been instructed to

> "POST the XML message using the arguments specified below. Be sure to include the <send> element and set its value to 'Y'. The POST response message will include a <message_id> element and a <message_key> element.

This is the provided format:

```
<api>
    <authentication>
        <api_key>ClientAPIKey</api_key>
        <shared_secret>ClientSharedSecret</shared_secret>
        <response_type>xml</response_type>
    </authentication>
    <data>
        <methodCall>
            <methodName>legacy.send_campaign</methodName>
            <grp>ClientEmailGroupCode</grp>
            <rich_mbody><![CDATA[<html...LONG HTML BLOCK...</html>]]></rich_mbody>
            <text_mbody><![CDATA[...LONG TEXT BODY...]]></text_mbody>
            <reply_email>ClientReplyEmail</reply_email>
            <from_email>ClientFromEmail</from_email>
            <fromdesc>ClientFromName</fromdesc>
            <msubject>ClientEmailSubject</msubject>
            <send>Y</send>
            <track_links>1</track_links>
        </methodCall>
    </data>
</api>
```

*The API is password protected, but I can post doc's upon request.*

I have confirmed the **ClientAPIKey**, **ClientSharedSecret**, and **ClientEmailGroupCode** as valid, but my testing has been unsuccessful.  Sending the following (using **fsockopen()** FWIW):

```
POST /api/xmlrpc/index.php HTTP/1.0
Host: echoN.bluehornet.com
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 21551

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<api>
    <authentication>...as above...</authentication>
    <data>...as above...</data>
</api>
```

causes the third-party server to send back this XML response indicating an error:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2011 13:18:50 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix)
Cache-Control: max-age=18000
Expires: Thu, 13 Oct 2011 18:18:50 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerBH-gen-80=387268618.20480.0000; path=/

<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<methodresponse><item><error><!--[CDATA[1]]--></error>
<responsetext><!--[CDATA[No XML Data Passed.]]--></responsetext>
<responsedata><responsenum><!--[CDATA[1]]--></responsenum>
<totalrequests><!--[CDATA[0]]--></totalrequests>
<totalcompleted><!--[CDATA[0]]--></totalcompleted>
</responsedata></item></methodresponse>
```

*Line breaks added for readability.*

The responseText of "No XML Data Passed." concerned me, so I contacted the vendor and was told to double check my URL (http vs. https, correct N in echo**N**.bluehornet..., etc.) and to be sure I was posting with the "data" parameter.  Suggestions were to place "?data=" at the end of the query URL in the HTTP header:

```
POST /api/xmlrpc/index.php?data= HTTP/1.0
```

or to prepend "data=" to the XML block in the request body:

```
data=<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

which seems to be implied by the code written for a .NET sister project:

```
private void ConstructData()
{
    data.Append("data=");
    data.Append("<api>");
    data.Append("<authentication>");
    data.Append(authenticationData.ToString());
    data.Append("</authentication>");
    data.Append("<data><methodCall>");
    data.Append(methodCallData.ToString());
    data.Append("</methodCall></data>");
    data.Append("</api>");
}
```

Modifying the query URL had no effect, and placing "data=" before the XML block caused a prolonged load time followed by no server response.

At this point, the vendor is trying to dig up a developer who has used the API before to weigh in on the issue.  In the meantime, I thought I'd share the above and see if anyone could point out any issues – minor oversights or glaring omissions as they may be – which might be causing my XML data not to be sent.

Comment: The third-party vendor finally got back to me with a revised version of their existing code which uses an entirely different method (cURL-based).  It seems that even the vendor was having issues with the above described technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If post really should look like data=xxx than you should probably send post data with this header

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And with post body, well, url encoded :)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Slartibartfast  I had tried "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as well as "text/xml" both with and without the charset info, but none were successful.  Turns out even the vendor is having issues with publishing with this API.  We're going to go with the suggested cURL method and just abandon this for now.

Answer (score 1):

This works.  Was hell of a time getting here.  Finally realized the ?data= was the field to pass in the payload.

```
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url = "https://echoN.bluehornet.com/api/xmlrpc/index.php"


    XML="""<api>
    <authentication>
    <api_key>000000000000000000</api_key>
    <shared_secret>00000000</shared_secret>
    <response_type>xml</response_type>
    </authentication>
    <data>
    <methodCall>
    <methodName>legacy.retrieve_active</methodName>
    <email>me@me.com</email>
    <return_groups>1</return_groups>
    </methodCall>
    </data>
    </api>"""


form_fields = {'data': XML}
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)

result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                        payload=form_data,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

print result.content
```

Answer (score 1):

It works when I removed the header line:

```
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ...
```

Final code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data' => $xml));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm no longer on this project, so I can't verify it, but I appreciate the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to get it working is POST XML as byte array with content-type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"